# How to stop innerHtml repeating itself over and over again in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, for-in-loop

I have made an array with objects that get there info from three different user variables, however on one of these there are many sub variables that i don't want it to repeat itself every time the user presses the select button(which updates the table) instead i want it to just add onto (or take away) from the sections that it already has in the table. thanks(if you need the variable code let me know) I have been trying to solve thi for a while now! please help!!

```
//creating array
var gProducts = new Array();
var gTotalCost = 0;



// Adding Products to array gProducts
    function addProduct
{
var product = new Object();
product.name = name;
product.cost = cost;
gProducts.push(product);
gTotalCost += parseInt(cost)
}


 //Getting products from array, use of for in loop setting new table rows in blank var for each array item
function renderProducts()
{
var HTMLadd = ""

for (var i in gProducts)
{
if( gProducts[i].cost > 0){
    HTMLadd = HTMLadd + 
    "<tr>"+ 
    "<td class='tableSettings00' id=tableRow2 >" + gProducts[i].name +
    "</td>"+
    "<td class='tableSettings'>€<span id=tableRow2part2>" + gProducts[i].cost +
    "</span></td>"+ 
    "</tr>";
    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
document.getElementById('tableRow').innerHTML = HTMLadd;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a for in loop, when you probably wanted just a for loop.

Change this line to

```
for (var i in gProducts)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < gProducts.length; i++)
```

With a for/in loop, the variable `i` will be an object, and not an integer.

Comment: thanks but i get the same result? everything still repeats itself!

Comment: Are you saying that every time `rederProducts()` is run, the table just adds the array over and over again, or that the array has repeats?

Comment: it adds the array over and over again! so theres the first array, then after when its updated there is the first as well as the new

Comment: That's very odd, the method replaces the innerHTML, when you update the array, are you checking for duplicates?

Comment: Something weird is going on, unfortunately I can't help you because the code you posted should work as it's replacing the innerHTML.

Comment: however i am calling the renderProducs(); function in the variables function, should i get rid of that?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the problem isn't here, it's somewhere else.